# After Create branch on GIT, why my Git Graph not Create a Branch too?

Tags: git

Im new on GIT,

I have using git maybe 1 month ago, I know how to use branch commit etc, but im still not understandh with the Graph.

this my sample

```
i create file tes.html

git init
git add *
git commit -a -m '1st_commit'

gitk --all

===============create branch=====
git branch cabang1 
git checkout cabang1

/*I modify code on cabang1*/

git commit -a -m cabang1

======create branch2======
git branch cabang2
git checkout cabang2

/*I modify code on cabang2*/

git commit -a -m cabang2

gitk --all
```

is nothing problem, but why my graph is like this picture
[image]

why the grap not create branch like this

```
   commit_cabang1    commit_cabang2
            |        |
   *--------*--------*
master    cabang1  cabang2
```

Can anyone here give me answer why my graph like that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your branches do not contain divergent commits, so your history of modifications is just what the graph shows: a linear history.

If, for example, you made a new commit on `cabang1` or `master` (commit that is not part of `cabang2`), then your graph would show what you expect:

```
git checkout cabang1
git commit -m 'divergent commit on cabang1' --allow-empty
```

---

Here's the output of [`git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+log+--oneline+--graph+--decorate+--all) before the commit:

```
* 91c2ad9 (HEAD, cabang2) cabang2
* 13a5e6c (cabang1) cabang1
* 478aa15 (master) 1st_commit
```

And here it is after the operation I have described above:

```
* 35be74c (HEAD, cabang1) divergent commit on cabang 1
| * 91c2ad9 (cabang2) cabang2
|/
* 13a5e6c cabang1
* 478aa15 (master) 1st_commit
```

Comment: i think -m is only for message, ok i'll try first